# Set Navit's internal keyboard language - Help!

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, keyboard, gui

I have an Rpi2 with Jessie and I have install Navit for navigation. I am from Greece and all the towns on my map are in Greek language.
I know navit only "knows" Latin and Cyrillic characters for the internal keyboard. In the Navit's support chat someone told me that I have to edit the **gui_internal_keyboard.c** file to implement Greek myself. 
Does anybody have any ideas about adding keyboard layouts in Navit?
Thanks!